# python how come function sees external variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def test1():
   print(x)

def test2(x):
   print(x)

x=1
test1()
test2(x)
```

When I run this python code, I get:

> 1
>
> 1

How can function test1 know about x, without passing it as an argument?

Comment: Because `x` is a global variable?

Comment: Variables are resolved when the statement is run, not when the function is declared. When you call test1, x exists in the global scope, therefore test1's code sees it.

Comment: See the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

Comment: Now that you know about global variables, use them sparingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable which is defined in the **main body** of a file is called a **global variable**.

It will be visible throughout the file, and also inside any file which imports that file.

[Read this](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Here `x` is a global varaible.

try the below code

```
def test1():
    x=2
    print(x)


def test2(x):
   print(x)

x=1
test1()
test2(x)
```

Here the output will be

```
2
1
```

Because test1 will print its local variable `x`.

You can use `global` keyword to modify the value of global variable `x` in `test1()`

```
def test1():
    global x
    x=2
    print(x)


def test2(x):
   print(x)

x=1
test1()
test2(x)
```

Output

```
2
2
```

Comment: @Shahar Thanks for marking as correct. Can you give an upvote too :)